# How to define a generic component and its corresponding configuration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic component that receive a react component and its config.
My generic component should render the react component and apply its corresponding config prop.

For example:

```js
type AProps = {
  name: string;
}

type BProps = {
  age: number;
}

type CProps = {
  address: string;
}
```

How can I call `MyGenericComp` with any component (be it `AProps` or `BProps` or `CProps`) so the config will be enforced?

I tried using generics like so:

```js
type MyGenericComp<T extends (_:any) => JSX.Element> = {
  component: T;
  config: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}
```

But it doesn't work quite well because I need to define the generic type and it doesn't work with array of `MyGenericComp`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use this sample code to pass components to CustomeComponent

```js
const AComponent=()=>{
  return (<div>A</div>)
  }
  const BComponent=()=>{
  return (<div>B</div>)
  }
  
  const CustomeComponent = ({Tag,...rest})=>{
  return(
  <Tag {...rest} />
  );
  }
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomeComponent Tag={AComponent} {...rest}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```